# required validation rule message show every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I have a fiddle in which i am using knockout.js. I created a custom validation for checking dupplicate entry in array and using a native validation `("required")`. Custom validation is working properly but native validation is not. Please take a lool to this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/3/

**EDIT**

You can re-generate the issue by first add empty entry and then add new entry.Than you will see that while adding empty entry you will not see the validation error message , you will see the message when you will add the valid entry.How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of the "field reset"

```
self.newItem(null);
```

Add `self.newItem.isModified(false);` after that to reset the modified status of the field.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/4/

Comment: You might also find it more flexible to use a validation group.  It will enforce all the errors on submission, solving the issue of the initial add not triggering a message (because the field had not changed).  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/5/

Comment: Using the validation group also gives a simpler way to "reset" the validation: `showAllMessages(false)`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/6/